# Как отобразить изображение в angular из spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, angular

В БД сохраняю url картинки

> **images/38557f62-cb4d-4711-92ac-eef1cc02194b.zdjecie-281-1.jpg**

В angular пытаюсь вывести изображение

```
    <img src="{{post.imagePath }}">
```

но получаю ошибку:

[image: Error]

Когда делаю так:

```
    <img src="http://localhost:8080/{{post.imagePath }}">
```

Все работает, но это костыль. Как можно это сделать без добавления хоста сервера

Comment: Вы должны в БД добавлять ссылку га изображение уже с хостом, тогда ни будет не каких проблем.

Comment: @OlegMarchenko это будет не костыль ?

Comment: Конечно нет, т.к. в будущем изображения могут переехать на другой сервер и тогда достаточно будет обновить данные в БД не исправляя шаблон.